# ERROR | prefect.flow_runs.runner - Process for flow run exited with status code: -7

Tags: python, prefect

I am getting this Prefect error while I am running my script. The error is the following:

`0%|          | 0/2070 [00:00<?, ?it/s]09:36:01.917 | ERROR   | prefect.flow_runs.runner - Process for flow run 'auspicious-butterfly' exited with status code: -7 09:36:02.057 | INFO    | prefect.flow_runs.runner - Reported flow run '1f314ccd-1472-4373-bb1b-4b3b6265b29a' as crashed: Flow run process exited with non-zero status code -7.`

No idea why's that. Any help would be appreciate it.